# PHP check if Request to other server is running

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, request

I'm working on an App which uses an API. I'm allowed to make only 2 requests per minute to the server. So I'm using my own server, which fetches the data 2 times per minute and my app requests the data from my server.
I have a database on my server, which stores the data I need. So if the user needs the data to be displayed on his smartphone or tablet, it fetches the data from my server.

I have a PHP script, which checks if the latest entry in my database is older than 30 seconds, if yes, the script will fetch the current data from the API server and stores it into my database.

But now, if there are e.g. 1000 users and everyone requests the current data at the same time - the script get's called a thousand times, and if the data in my database is older than 30 seconds, it fetches the data from the API server - does my server make requests to the API server as long as the current data isn't available in my database? I'm worried that I exceed the 2 requests/minute.

Comment: _“does my server make requests to the API server as long as the current data isn't available in my database?”_ – well that depends on your specific implementation of the whole thing, don’t you think …?

Comment: Maybe you should not (only) store the information how old the current data is, but rather the last time a request for new data to that API was triggered? If the next script instance sees, _“OK, the last request for this data was triggered only five seconds ago”_ … then don’t let it trigger another request right now.

Comment: My script only makes one request to the server - after I get the response, I store the data. But is there are 1000 requests to my server, is my server then doing 1000 requests to the API server? I don't now how to implement this.. :/

Comment: There is no reason the caller to the application server should be triggering requests to the server that holds the source data.  You should de-couple these activities.

Comment: The server is running the Parallels Plesk Panel (v11.5.30), but I think I don't have the permission to create cron jobs.. so cron jobs are not the optimal solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cron job to pull the data from the server exactly every 30 seconds and  cut out the  part where it double checks on every single request. That is redundant if you already have a cron job doing it.

[Here's something.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

EDIT

If crons are not an option you could try using a file lock.

The idea is that when a request is made you put a lock on a file in your filesystem and take the lock off once the request is completed. Every time a request is made, check to see if the file is locked, if so it means someone else is currently triggering the request and it's safe to skip. If the file is unlocked you can store the current time-stamp in it and check if that time-stamp is older than 30 seconds.

```
// get current time by reading the file. You will need to create the file manually initially with the timestamp in it
$last_run = file_get_contents('foo.txt');

// open the file
$fp = fopen("foo.txt", "w");

// check if file is locked
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {

    // check that it's been more than 30 seconds
    if($last_run > (time() - 30)){

        // if file is unlocked update it with current timestamp
        $fwrite($fp, time());

        // make request to server, upload to db

        // after request has been made, unlock the file
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

    }

} else {

    // someone else is triggering the request, get data from db

}
```

[Here's something else..](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0)

Comment: cron can only execute in 1 minute intervals, so if you want to use this approach you will need to build a timer in the script to fire a second request ~30 seconds after first one.

Comment: The server is running the Parallels Plesk Panel (v11.5.30), but I think I don't have the permission to create cron jobs.. so cron jobs are not the optimal solution in my case.

Comment: @MikeBrant or simply have 2 cron jobs that run the same script every minute, offset by 30 seconds from one another.

Comment: @beeef What harm is caused by requesting the data more often than allowed? Will you actually get in trouble or will the API just ddeny the request? If the latter, then just fall back on the data in the database.

Comment: I think I can make as many requests as I want, but if I'm doing more than 2 requests all day long, then my API-Key won't be valid any more and I need a new one (if I get one). I only get a response from the server if my unique API key is valid. But I don't want my API key to get invalidated.

Comment: maybe I'll try that one, thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Adelphia I am not aware of any means by which cron can specify one script to start on the minute and one to start with 30 second offset.